# AsyncTask Array creation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I trying to create AsyncTask array for my Android project
to assign data to TextView's. I need separate tasks for each city data.

My single AsyncTask working ok so I presume main method is fine.
Problem starts when I try to create arrays of tasks.

I getting error `Attempt to invoke virtual method on null reference`

Array task execute exactly same code as single task so problem must be how I created array

I posting whole Main Activity to show what I try to do. With both single and array tasks.
I would be grateful for any help.

```
private LinearLayout editLayout;
private LinearLayout layout1;
private LinearLayout layout2;
private LinearLayout layout3;
private LinearLayout layout4;
int n;
TextView[] city = new TextView[10];
TextView[] time = new TextView[10];
TextView[] temperature = new TextView[10];


private ImageView delete1;
private ImageView delete2;
private ImageView delete3;
private ImageView delete4;

private ImageView condition1;
private ImageView condition2;
private ImageView condition3;
private ImageView condition4;

Weather weather = new Weather();
Task task = new Task();
Task task1 = new Task();
private Task[] myTasks = new Task[10];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    editLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layEdit);
    layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay2);
    layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay3);
    layout4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay4);

    city[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city1);
    city[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city2);
    city[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city3);
    city[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city4);

    time[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time1);
    time[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time2);
    time[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time3);
    time[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time4);

    temperature[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp1);
    temperature[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp2);
    temperature[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp3);
    temperature[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp4);

    delete1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delete1);
    delete2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delete2);
    delete3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delete3);
    delete4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delete4);

    condition1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun1);
    condition2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun2);
    condition3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun3);
    condition4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun4);
    //weatherData("Paris, France");

    //weatherData("Paris, France", 0);
    loadTask(1,"Dublin, Ireland" );




private void loadTask(int sInt, String city){
    this.n=n;
    myTasks[sInt].execute(new String[]{city + "&APPID="+ WeatherApiNumber + "&units=metric"});
}
public void weatherData(String city, int n){
    this.n=n;
    task1.execute(new String[]{city + "&APPID="+ WeatherApiNumber + "&units=metric"});

}
private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather>{

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data = ((new WeatherClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));
        weather = Parser.getWeather(data);

        return weather;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
        super.onPostExecute(weather);

        cityData(n);

    }

}
public void cityData(int n){

    city[n].setText(weather.place.getCity());
    time[n].setText(Integer.toString(weather.place.getTimeZone()));
    temperature[n].setText(Double.toString(weather.temp.getTemp()).substring(0,2));
    //task.cancel(true);


}
public void cityData2(int n){
    ;
    city[n].setText(weather.place.getCity());
    time[n].setText(Integer.toString(weather.place.getTimeZone()));
    temperature[1].setText(Double.toString(weather.temp.getTemp()).substring(0,2));
    //task.cancel(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to your task array myTasks

in this line you are only initializing the array but not the array items.

```
private Task[] myTasks = new Task[10];
```

You should, at some point, assign a task to a cell in myTasks and only then call execute on it

Comment: Something like myTasks[0] = new Task();
        myTasks[1] = new Task();
        myTasks[2] = new Task();
        myTasks[3] = new Task();?

Comment: Exactly. But why would you need a reference to these AsyncTast objects after you launch them?

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with with this. What I plan to do is to create separate layouts all as arrays. Inside them values for city names, temp etc. also as arrays. I want each layout to be generated by separate task. So they work independently in same time. I was planing to use threads first with I'm more familiar. But I saw that everyone using those AsyncTasks now. But now I'm little lost.

Comment: you should use some native view that support lists or array (AdapterView) like RecyclerView.

Comment: Another thing about AsyncTasks, when you launch more than one at the same time, they will not run in parallel unless you explicitly define so using an Executor. By default they run one after another

Comment: Yeah I saw that. I don't understand why this is happening. Those are separate tasks. With separate variables. Why they don't go same time?

Comment: That's the default behaviour. If you want to override it use executeonexecutor
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask?hl=en#executeonexecutor

Comment: I did something like that  myTasks[n].executeOnExecutor(Task.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, city + "&APPID=" + WeatherApiNumber + "&units=metric"); But it still don't run 2 tasks. One go after another:(

Comment: I also make this in onPostExecute

int a = 0;
if(a==0||n==a){
    a=n;

}
if (a!=n) {
    a = a;
}

So task use local variable instead calling global that is changed when new task is activated